# xamarin forms - after installing apk the application does not open

Tags: xamarin.forms, apk

The installation completes successfully but does not run.
I put a permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

in the Manifest file as suggested by some and it still did not open.

Comment: use adb to look at the system log files

Comment: No assemblies found in ... or storage/emulated/.../Android/data ...
I realized yesterday this problem but how to solve the problem? Is apk not an installer that solves everything for us?

Comment: I unchecked the option Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only) and it worked.

Comment: @Jason Do you have a link to some documentation about where to find this adb and how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

I unchecked the option Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only) and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me too, but very strange that it even works when I only check this off in Debug mode and still it helped with the release apk